# Codeigniter Insert Batch array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am Inserting a multiple form input data in to database using Codeigniter.
I have this post input array:

```
 Array
(
 [subject_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
    )

[question] => Array

    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => test2
    )

[option1] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => test2
    ) )
```

I don't get that how do i convert this array to insert How to insert this array using Insert batch.

```
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

This is the form code which i use for posting the data:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="subject_id[]" >
    <input type="text" name="question[]" >
    <input type="text" name="record[]" >

    // Down side Part is appended when user want to add more question

    <input type="text" name="subject_id[]" >
    <input type="text" name="question[]" >
    <input type="text" name="record[]" >

    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

Below is the Array format which i want.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'subject_id' => 'My title' ,
        'question' => 'My Name' ,
        'option1' => 'My date'
        ),
    array(
        'subject_id' => 'Another title' ,
        'question' => 'Another Name' ,
        'option1' => 'Another date'
        )
    );
```

Comment: post your code in your question regarding how do you get this array?

Comment: Sir I Have updated the question. @dhruvjadia

Comment: I have updated the question again sir & added what the result array i need.  @dhruvjadia

Comment: provided answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($subject_id as $key=>$val)
    {
          $data[$i]['subject_id'] = $val;
          $data[$i]['question'] = $question[$key];
          $data[$i]['option1'] = $record[$key];
          $i++;
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like below:Assume `$records` is an array that you want to insert.

```
foreach ($records as $record) 
{

    for ($i=0; $i < count($record); $i++) 
    {   
    $data[$i]['subject_id'] = $record['subject_id'][$i];
    $data[$i]['question'] = $record['question'][$i]
    $data[$i]['option1'] = $record['option1'][$i];
    }

}
```

Then

```
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: are you getting value of `$records['subject_id'][0]` properly.

Comment: what is the name of array that you are posting in question.

Comment: I give it the $records = array(); and so on.

Comment: I have updated the question again sir & added what the result array i need.  @hekmat